# What do I do with unwanted equipment?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-mansion-monster-manor

What do I do with unneeded equipment in *Monster Manor*? I picked up an `Atomic Ray` soon after starting the game and don't need my `Rusty Blaster` anymore. Can I sell/trade/trash it at some point (I assume the gems I keep collecting can be used to buy something at a store at some point)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the Mystic Orb!

Mystic Orbs are encountered the same as treasure chests and StreetPass tags in rooms: Make a 2×2 room and either a Treasure Chest, StreetPass Tag or Mystic Orb will spawn.

Mystic Orbs allow players to store items, upgrade weapons (combine weapons and spend gems) and sell items for gems.

Two weapons of the same type may be combined to increase the max level of the weapon.

Should you expand the room again the orb will refresh and you can use it again.